# Azure Pipeline Secret environment variables marked as undefined

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

When I mark an environment variable (Pipeline -> Library) as a **secret**, I can't seem to access it in my pipeline runs.

For instance, when I try to access the variable, Node.js marks it as `undefined`.

The following is my import code from the Azure Pipelines YAML file:

```
variables:
- group: Foo-Bar-Variables
```

Is there any way for me to access the **secret** variables? I prefer to not store them as plain-text.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: @PatrickGoode I would have manually declare each secret variable in my yaml file too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to access the secret variables? I prefer to not store them as plain-text.

Just like the official document [Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables), we could to know:

> Each task that needs to use the secret as an environment variable does
>   remapping. If you want to use a secret variable called `mySecret` from
>   a script, **use the Environment section of the scripting task's input
>   variables**. Set the environment variable name to `MYSECRET`, and set
>   the value to `$(mySecret)`.

```
- task: xxxx
  displayName: 'xxxx'
  env:
    SOMEVAR: '$(TestVar)'
  inputs:
```

Besides, currently, we have to manually declare all the secret variables that we will used in the yaml file.

Hope this helps.